# How to delete react app & open existing one

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am beginner for React-App. I have an existing project folder.

Step I took:

```
npm install -g create-react app
cd C:\Users\MyFolder\Documents\MyName\CS50\Project\Project1
npm start
```

**
"This automatically create a folder called "start" inside my Project1 with folders & files below:

```
node_modules
public
src
.gitignore
package.json
package-lock.json
README.md
```

**

Actually I already have all the files inside Project1, eg:

```
.gitignore
assets folder
utils folder
.babelrc
.watchmanconfig
App.js
app.json
package.json
README.md
```

How can I delete the start folder inside C:\Users\MyFolder\Documents\MyName\CS50\Project\Project1
and I want to open the Project1 folder to work on the assignment given by a course I am attending online. This is my 1st time doing it.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Regards,

Micheale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't the right way to use `create-react-app`.

Firstly, run

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Then go into the directory where you wish to create the project and run

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Yes, it is `npx` and not `npm`. Its not a typo.

Finally,

```
cd app-name
npm start
```

This will launch a test server and open it up on chrome.

As far as deleting goes, just navigate to the folder you want to delete with your File Explorer and Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

## Create React App

**step** 1: First you create folder "my-first-app"
**step** 2: Go to your `vsCode` and open that folder
**step** 3: Open terminal on your `vscode` and create your react app `npx create-react-app my-app`
**step** 4: Next `cd my-app`
**step** 5: Finally `npm start`

please don't create a folder inside folder "C:\Users\MyFolder\Documents\MyName\CS50\Project\Project1".It's not a good approach of coding

you don't have a any file use `npm remove <place it your removing file>)`

## Removing a local package from your node_modules directory

1. Unscoped package. `npm remove` <package_name>
2. Scoped package. `npm remove` <@scope/package_name>
3. Unscoped package. `npm remove` --save <package_name>
4. Scoped package. `npm remove` --save <@scope/package_name>
5. Example. npm remove --save lodash

Answer (score 0):

Delete and remove the react-app Files faster in a seconds using

```
rm -rf <nameOfTheFolder> // or name of the project
```

This 100% work, upvote it coz otherwise it takes, lot of time to remove using simple delete from the terminal.

Save all programmers time #GivingBackToCommunity thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).